# How to delete an IP address when you don't have the net table entry context

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming

The [DeleteIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function can be used to remove an IP address which was added at an earlier time using [AddIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You obtain the net table entry context when you add the address and pass it as a parameter to DeleteIPAddress.

In my case, there must be a reboot between the time that the IP address is added and when we want to remove it. The address is persistent and remains after the reboot but we no longer have the net table entry context so DeleteIPAddress fails. How else can I remove this IP address?

I'm working with C++ on Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the following at ms; `GetAdaptersInfo` should be what you need

> DeleteIPAddress fails in Windows XP when deleting an IP address not added using AddIPAddress
>   In Windows 7, I can delete an IP address using DeleteIPAddress() even though I did not add it using AddIPAddress(). I can do this by getting the NTEContext of the desired IP address of a specific network adapter via GetAdaptersInfo().
>
> This does not seem to work on Windows XP SP3 Professional. DeleteIPAddress() returns an error ERROR_GEN_FAILURE "A device attached to the system is not functioning.". All other preceding and succeeding calls to IP Helper functions succeeds so there is nothing wrong with my device.